# How to use passport.js for different kinds user authentication?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to have 2 different users by having 2 collections in my MongoDB database. So, I wants to have
separate authentication. I had done this.

```js
    passport.use('patient', new LocalStrategy({usernameField:'email'},
    function(username, password, done){
        patient.findOne({email: username}).then(user => {
            if(!user){
                console.log("no patient exists");
                return done(null, false);
            }
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (isMatch) {
                  return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    console.log("incorrect patient password");
                  return done(null, false);
                }
              });
        })
    }));
```

And I had serialized and deserialized my passport.

```js
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log(user._id );
    console.log(user.speciality);
    done(null, {id: user._id, isPatient: user.speciality===undefined});});
    passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    // User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    //   done(err, user);
    // });
    if(user.isPatient){
        patient.findById(user.id, function(err, user){
            done(err, user);
        });
    }else{
        doctor.findById(user.id, function(err, user){
            done(err, user);
        })
    }});
```

But when I'm trying to login my website is only loading but ain't showing any error or redirecting.
Please help me.

Comment: Maybe you can have two separate routes one for `/doctor` and one for `/patient`? Then you could have two local strategies that use the associated doctor/patient data model to query for a user.

Comment: But what is the problem here? My login page is just loading and not showing any results.